# Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code , it is reading the value from a text box, I thought checking for '' before trying to parseInt() would be safe , but apparently not.

I am getting the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined

With this code:

```
            var total = 0;
            $.each('.reg-input', function () {
                if ($(this).val() == '') {
                }
                else {
                    total += parseInt($(this).val());  //this line throwing error
                }                    
            });
            if (total == 0) {
                $('.RegisterContainer').hide();                    
            }
```

Comment: Try fixing the brackets `total += parseInt($(this).val());`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `total += parseInt(this.val());`?

Comment: that was pasting it problem , I have the right bracket in code

Comment: Has no one read the error? Where are you actually using `'toLowerCase'`?!? Wherever you're calling `.toLowerCase()` the object being referenced is `undefined`.

Comment: @zzzzBov It's within the `$()` method or `.val()` depending on where it fails. he's iterating through a string, not a collection of elements. That's where the real problem lies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`'.reg-input'` is a string, `this` in that case will also be a string, not a dom element. Try this instead:

```
$('.reg-input').each(function(){...
```

Comment: @ScottSelby, Kevin was first on this one. Make sure to order by oldest, and you'll see Kevin's post first.

Answer (score 4):

The reason that you get the strange error is that you are calling `$.each` with a string instead of a collection.

A string is an object, so it's still a collection, but the items in the collection is the properties and methods of the string class (and `toLowerCase` is one of them).

To loop through the elements that you find with a selector, you use the [`each` method](http://api.jquery.com/each/) instead of the [`$.each` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

```
$('.reg-input').each(function(){
  ..
});
```

Now `this` inside the loop will be an element, not a member of the string class, so you can use `$(this).val()` to get the values.

Comment: thanks , good catch , it didn't help at all that I left a little typo - missing ')', then trying to tell people that isn't the problem

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem, and I solved it by assigning `$(this).val()` to a variable and then parse the variable to an integer. So a correct workaround would be:

```
var total = 0;
        $.each('.reg-input', function () {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
            }
            else {
                $this_val = $(this).val();
                total += parseInt($this_val);  //this line throwing error
            }                    
        });
        if (total == 0) {
            $('.RegisterContainer').hide();                    
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

`if ($(this).val() == "")` 
checks to see if the value is the string "" not undefined.
You can use the typeof operator like this
 `if(typeof $(this).val() == 'undefined')`

Comment: Not quite sure why this got down voted... there is a major difference in checking for the string '' and for something that is undefined... OP you should really give it a shot...

Comment: It has nothing to do with the question being asked.

Comment: Yes it does, He is getting into the else {} because his if statement is failing...  If his if statement catches that $(this) is undefined it will not go onto the else, and will validate in the manner the OP is seeking... and he WILL NOT get the error...

EDIT:  if you want a more generic answer... no... .val() is not safe to evaluate undefined...

Comment: But the issue is with the error, not with the mislabeled title of the question.

Comment: @JLeslie - if the val() is undefined using jQuery's .val() will turn it into and empty string , that is why that line is in there , you're line also works